# Is there a way to test Android App development through one PC & Emulation through on another connected locally?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-testing

I Plan to use two computers both has low disk space and Not so great Processor & RAM for Android Development. So, I wonder if I could find a way to connect both of my PCs in the same WLAN N/W or by any means, One running Android Studio and the other with Android Emulator. If Possible multiple Emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure on how you could have 2 pc's simultaneously working together here.

But you could look into version control such as Git and Bitbucket.

If you set something like git up on 2 different pc's you can have 2 different projects. The one you control the source code and the other one you just run from.

What this would mean is that you could code on the one pc, push (putting the code on an online repository) and then pull on the other pc (grabs this code from the respoistory) and run.

[You may find this useful](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)